# How to Auto Fill Date Column (with +30days) form Another Date Column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 Columns like this

[image]

Where :

1. Start date is inputed by user
2. Finish Date is automatically filled with (Start Date + 30 days)

I have used this formula in Finish Date Column

`=date(year(A:A),month(A:A),day(A:A)+30)`

It works well, But the formula will work if we drag the blue box any number of cells down. I want to make it automatically filled after we input the start date. I also have read that we should use some script but I don't uderstand. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please correct your tag list, you have excel tags, but your question refers to GoogleSheet. In order to achieve what you want, just do: startDate + `60` or using array formula: `ARRAYFOORMULA(if(A2:A="","", A2:A+60))`

Comment: @DavidLeal Sorry, and Thank you for your help! It works well and its indeed what I need. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have start dates in `A2:A`, then array way to obtain the corresponding end date (30 days after) on each row is as follow in `B2` cell.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A="","", A2:A+30))
```

**Note**: You can also put the condition like this: `if(A2:A="",, A2:A+30)` or just:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(if(LEN(A2:A),A2:A+30,))
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need, thanks! but you write foormula with double o

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PebriAlkautsar updated the answer, I added some minor clarifications on other ways to express it.